# How do I call a Swift function from Objective-C that has a hidden variable name (_ before parameter) or an internal + external (e.g. foo(with bar:))

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use Swift code in my Objective-C module and have already:

- Imported <Module-Swift.h>
- Set @objc in front of each class & function I intended to use in Objective-C

Yet I'm still struggling to use Swift functions in Objective-C with either hidden variable names (with an underscore), or with both an internal & external variable name. How would I call either of the following functions in Objective-C?

**Swift Code:**

```
@objc
public final class FeedUpdateAttachmentHelper : NSObject {
    @objc
    func myFunction(_ postMetadata: PostMetadata) {
         ...
    }
    @objc
    func secondFunction(for postMetadata: PostMetadata) {
         ...
    }
}
```

**How I've tried to call them in Objective-C:**

```
[myFunction postMetadata:postMetadata];

[secondFunction forPostMetadata:postMetadata];
```

Both are giving me the following error:

> No known class method for selector, "function/secondFunction"

Answer (score 3):

You can always see the Objective-C interface for your Swift class by CMD+CTRL clicking on `#import YourModuleName-Swift.h`.

In this case it looks like:

```
@interface FeedUpdateAttachmentHelper : NSObject
- (void)myFunction:(PostMetadata * _Nonnull)postMetadata;
- (void)secondFunctionFor:(PostMetadata * _Nonnull)postMetadata;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

And would be used like this:

```
-(void)doThing {
    
    FeedUpdateAttachmentHelper *helper = [[FeedUpdateAttachmentHelper alloc] init];
    PostMetadata *metadata = [[PostMetadata alloc] init];
    [helper myFunction:metadata];
    [helper secondFunctionFor:metadata];
    
}
```